# Android Timer doesn't work well

Tags: android

```
private int count = 0;
private float totalmoney = 0, constant=(1/3);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    textView.setText("minutes= " + count + " money= " + totalmoney);
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Timer T = new Timer();
            T.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            count++;
                            totalmoney = totalmoney+constant;
                            textView.setText("minutes= " + count + " money= " + totalmoney);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 60000, 60000);

        }
    });
}
```

Hello all, I want to have a timer, running every minute, starting from 0 and every minute add (1/3) to the `totalmoney` float, My code is above, it is working very well, the minutes count is also working good but the `totalmoney` is permanently zero. I tried at first using `totalmoney += (1/3)` but it didn't work so I changed my code a bit with a constant of (1/3), why does it stay zero?

Comment: So you want to add 0.33 to your total money every minute?

Comment: @DJMethaneMan Actually I will prefer 1/3 so it will complete to one and not 0.99 , why, is that the problem?

Comment: GuyBalas See @AnindyaDutta's answer, it looks like he has it covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float constant = 1/3`

Here 1/3 is first divided as integers, hence 1/3 = 0. Then it is converted to float (becomes 0.00...).
Effectively, you are always adding 0 to your `totalmoney`.

Update the constant to `(float)1/3` or `1f/3` and the code should be working fine.

Comment: If I put some constant value of float it will divide it as integer, why is that? anyway, thank you :) I think when you creating a float it should be as float and not integer.. sorry for my English..

Comment: This is because while evaluating, it would first divide the RHS. Since there is no mention of float in the RHS, 1 and 3 are just normal integers, which will be divided by integer arithmetic (since the highest precision operand is still `int`. When it is later assigned to a float, then the precision would change. 

However, mentioning `1f`  instead of `1` would make one of the operands of a higher precision. And so the entire value would become `float`.

Comment: @GuyBalas, Also, in case you find the answer helpful, please accept it as an answer so that others might find it useful too.

Comment: Sure, I just couldn't accept it because it was "too early" , thx.